# Record Set - No current record

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am having some difficulty with record sets.

**CODE:**

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tbl_Suggestions_Historic WHERE ID = ' " & ID & " '")

    rs.Edit
    rs("Status") = "Closed By User"
    rs("ReasonClosed") = ClosedWhy
    rs.Update

Set rs = Nothing
```

**PROBLEM:**
I have a list box with a list of accounts. When an account is click a textbox populates with the record id, I want the changes to update that particular record.

**ERROR:**
The message received is 'No Current Record'

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What type is your "ID"  column? If you quote the value, I'm assuming it's a text column? In this case, try to omit the blank spaces, i.e. change ID = ' " & ID & " '" to  ID = '" & ID "'. If it's not a text field, don't quote at all, i.e. ID = " & ID & ";"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The likely error is that your ID column is a number, not a string, and thus you should remove the quotes:

```
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tbl_Suggestions_Historic WHERE ID = " & ID)
```

If it is a string, you need to be mindful of your spaces. You're including a space before and a space after the ID.

However, this is a good use case for an update query instead of a recordset. Imo, you should remove all your recordset code, and just use this:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE tbl_Suggestions_Historic SET [Status] = 'Closed By User', [ReasonClosed] = '" & ClosedWhy & "' WHERE ID = " & ID
```

Or, if you want to do it properly, use parameters. I haven't used them since you didn't

See below for an example using parameters

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Set db = CurrentDb
Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef("","UPDATE tbl_Suggestions_Historic SET [Status] = 'Closed By User', [ReasonClosed] = ? WHERE ID = ?" )
qdf.Parameters(1) = ClosedWhy
qdf.Parameters(2) = ID
qdf.Execute
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice - I ran the SQL directly instead as suggested and it worked fine. I'm still learning so do appreciate the help

Comment: @dmorgan20 if you're still learning, you better learn how to do it properly. See the example underneath to use parameters, this both prevents errors if one of your strings (e.g. ClosedWhy) contains apostrophes, and for most applications, it helps keep it secure (for Access, this is less relevant)